# How to store NSData from NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest as a pdf file to documents directory in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am getting the `NSData` using

```
NSData * responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:mutableUrlRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

How to store this as a PDF to local documents directory? My service is in java which returns byte array.

Thanks !

Comment: are you getting the `responceData` correctly ? Did you checked whether it is null or not ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Ya I am getting responseData properly. Its not null. Please advice

Comment: Are you sure you are requesting the file is pdf file?

Comment: Yes I am sure, the response type of the service is byte array of the pdf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
NSString *docPath=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
[data writeToFile:[docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"name.pdf"] 
       atomically:YES];
```

Comment: are you getting data object check its length and go to doc path and check the file is created or not.

Comment: The file is creating but the length of NSData is comparatively very small.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to confirm that your request has been successful:

- Provide a pointer for the response which on return contains the status code and the MIME type of the response data, possibly also content length and other useful info. Check against what you expect.
- Provide a NSError pointer, too  in order to get the error when the connection fails (returns nil).

That's what you should always do when you make a *toy* app. When you make a more serious app, you should use the *asynchronous style* to perform a network request. Basically, you implement the two `NSURLConnection` Delegate protocols. There is lot of info already in SO how to accomplish this, and as well in Apple samples. If you have any specific questions, please ask again :)

> How to store this as a PDF to local documents directory?

This question has been answered already.